# How add custom dither filter with paletted image in gift library (go/golang)

Tags: go

Iam using Go image filter library https://github.com/disintegration/gift.

I tried implement `gift.Filter` interface with method `Draw` below. But the result is plain white image only. Is there something wrong with my code? Or How to implement `gift.Filter` with paletted image source?

```
func (f ditherFilter) Draw(dst draw.Image, src image.Image, options *gift.Options) {
    dst = image.NewPaletted(src.Bounds(), color.Palette{color.Black, color.White})
    draw.FloydSteinberg.Draw(dst, src.Bounds(), src, image.ZP)
}
```

reference: https://golang.org/pkg/image/draw/

Thanks.